# Assign map values to class properties

Tags: flutter, dart

if for example i had a map

```
{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'John' }
```

and I want to assign map values to class properties: Map keys are the properties and map values are the values for properties.

My Code :

```
class Person {
  late int id;
  late String name;

  Person.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    // Solution 1
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];

    // I want a better solution
    for (var key in json.keys) {
      print('${key} - ${json[key]}');
      // id - 1
      // name - John

      // this[key] = json[key]; ?
      // HOW CAN I DO THIS?
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  Person p = Person.fromJson({
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'John',
  });

  print('${p.id} - ${p.name}');
}
 ``
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `factory` constructors in this case, but first, you need to declare the class default constructor, so we will create an instance of that class constructor from the `factory` one, using the `Map<String, dynamic>`:

```
// add this
Person({
  required this.id,
  required this.name,
 });

// then add this
factory Person.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
  
  return Person(
     id: json['id'] as int,
     name: json['id'] as String,
   );
  }
```

and now you can use the `Person.fromJson()` as you expect in your code:

```
 void main() {
  Person p = Person.fromJson({
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'John',
  });

  print('${p.id} - ${p.name}');
}
```

Comment: this is not what i want , i want to remove `id = json['id'];
    name = json['name']; `i want instance automatically take all json entries as properties
`

Answer (score 1):

Manually writing out the toJson/fromJson methods is time consuming and not scalable. I would recommend using [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation).

To do this, you simply create your class with the final properties you want and annotate it with @JsonSerializable()

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'person.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Person{

  final String name;
  final int id;

  Person({
    required this.name,
    required this.id,


  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}
```

Then just run the build command and everything will be generated for you.

`flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Comment: what about creating a superclass with a **fromJson** method which automatically add all JSON key & values as attributes ... this is what I want to do here

Comment: @d3ridi There currently is no automatic way to generate objects from `Map`s in Dart.  Using code generation (such as using `package:json_serializable` or `package:built_value`) is the proper thing to do.